# Does an Inkjet printer support Zebra Programming language (ZPL) to print labels or pages?

Tags: c#-4.0, zpl, zpl-ii

I used to print labels using a Zebra GX430t printer as I have used ZPL commands in my software.
Now I have an Inkjet printer, and same software is not printing label on this type of printer. 
Can someone please tell me if the InkJet printers supports ZPL (Zebra Programming Language) or not?

Comment: Well, of course not.  ZPL is a proprietary printing language that's only supported by Zebra printers.  A business strategy called "vendor tie in", forces you to buy another Zebra printer.

Comment: It is not true that ZPL is only supported by Zebra printers. Some models of Epson printers support ZPL (I am using ZPL with the TM-C3400 right now). It _is_ true not to _expect_ printers to support ZPL.

Answer (score 3):

ZPL II is also supported (or emulated) by many other printer producers such as: IBM Printer Systems, Intermec Technologies, TSC, Eltron (Zebra Technologies), Printronix, Avery Dennison.

Comment: This is more a comment then an answer. please integrate into the stack overflow community, get your required information and please do not add such answers. thanks!

Comment: Actually this is an answer as I see it, although not complete. ZPL II is [fully documented](https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/zpl_manual.pdf) and is sort of the "standard language" for label printers and inline thermal printers (TTO) used in industrial applications. The question was for *inkjet* specifically. Your typical home inkjet would probably not understand ZPL natively. But some industrial inkjet printers such as [Videojet (Wolke) m600](https://www.videojet.in/in/homepage/products/thermal-Ink-jet/videojet-8520-wolke-m610-touch.html) actually implements a subset of ZPL.

Answer (score 1):

ZPL is proprietary and will only be hosted on Zebra label printers.  So, your software will not work on your InkJet printer.